# How to integrate google forms with android webview?

Tags: android, webview, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Is there a way to integrate google forms with android webview ? 
I have a simple requirement wherein several users will be filling up a google forms on an android tablet. End results will be stored in a google drive spreadsheet. But the only problem with this approach is if network is not available then users can not fill up these form.
As a workaround for this I am thinking of creating a android interface which will store the data in a local db and as and when network is available data will be posted to google docs.
Since the forms are likely to be changed is there a way to dynamically create android UI from google forms or sort of have a dynamic offline version of google forms in android so that I dn't have to change the android UI each time a new field is added to the form .
Thanks 
Shakti

Comment: I do have the same issue. were u able to figure out this?

Comment: @sureshcheemalamudi not yet . Going with an alternative way to store data in local application and sync remotely as and when users are on network.